# PHP: Does array have key that is value in another array

Tags: php, arrays

so for example I have an associative array like

```
array( "a" => 23, "b" => 48, "c" => 10, "d" => 19 )
```

Let's call it ArrayA. 
And another array (ArrayB) that is

```
array( "a", "c" )
```

I want to get ArrayA's keys that do not occur in ArrayB, which would be "b" and "d".

I haven't found anything useful when googling but I assume that there is a php function for that or how would you solve this as fancy as possible?

Comment: `array_diff_key($arrayA, array_flip($arrayB))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare all values in php array with the other values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483216/compare-all-values-in-php-array-with-the-other-values)

Comment: `array_diff(array_keys($a), $b)`

Comment: thank you Mark and Ruslan, this is what I expected :) both work, I'll go with the shorter one

Answer (score 0):

You can doit with **array_diff()** and **array_keys()**
Manual array_diff: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php
Manual array_keys: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

With array_diff() the function returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.
And with array_keys() will return the keys, numeric and string, from the array. You can add specific search options with this function to.

```
<?php
$ArrayA = array("a" => 23, "b" => 48, "c" => 10, "d" => 19);
$ArrayB = array("a", "c");
$result = array_diff(array_keys($ArrayA), $ArrayB);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Regards